# What does !s || !*s mean? (s is char*)

Tags: c, string

I'm struggling to understand what this part means:

```
 if (!s || !*s) //What is this?!?!
      {
        printf("\n");
        return;
      }
```

Here's my main function:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func1(char *s);

int main()
{
    func1("SABABA");
    return 0;
}
```

And my func1:

```
void func1(char *s)
{
    int a, b, c;
    if (!s || !*s)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    b = strlen(s);
    while (b>2)
    {
        a = 0;
        if (s[a] == s[b - 1])
        {
            for (c = b - 1; c >= a && s[a] == s[c]; a++, c--);
            if (c<a)
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i<b; i++)
                    printf("%c", s[i]);
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        b--;
    }
    func1(s + 1);
}
```

**My opinion:** 's' represents the adress of the string, and !s represents when we're outside the "stack" of the string. for example if the beginning address is 1000 and the string is 6 chars, we end up in 1006. if we exceed 1006 , for e.g. to 1007 then it !s returns true. and about *s, it checks what value the adress 1000 holds, which is "S" which is true, meaning !*s is false. and because we know that every string ends with "/0" which will be, I guess at 1007, we search for that. If I'm right, then why we need both !s and *s, why not just one of them. Did I get this even right?

Comment: Read up on pointers in an introductory book on C. `!s` checks that `s` is not a null pointer, `!*s` dereferences `s` and checks that it does not point to a NUL character.

Comment: Those are awful variable and function names! :D

Comment: @mikeyq6 It is taken from a test. It just 7 points, to determine what this function does and its output. I think they've written it in 1997.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!s` is checking `s` is not a null pointer.

`!*s` is checking the char `s` pointing to is not `'\0'`, that means `s` is not an empty string.

The check doesn't match the invoking `func1("SABABA")`, but is prepared for such as `func1(0)` or `func1("")`.

Comment: Why !s is necessary?  It is not a dync. allocation.  Which means "SABABA" will be assigned to s, which will clearly have a memory. or maybe if RAM is full it will return a null pointer?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Why do you think it shouldn't?  Suppose `s` was null, what would happen if you tried to deference it? Just because you specifically call the function with a non-null string, doesn't mean it always would and you shouldn't assume that it would.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS `func1()` doesn't know how it will be called, and what will be passed, doesn't it? Think about `func1(0)` and `func1("")`.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS it might not be necessary to check for `!s`. It depends on whether the person who wrote the specification for the function wanted it to handle null pointers or not. The specification could just as easily prohibit passing a null pointer value to the function, in which case, the programmer wouldn't need to code for it especially (but might decide to do so regardless).

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (!s || !*s)` checks if the pointer `s` is a null pointer or if the target of the pointer is `'\0'`.The former check is needed because you may supply this function with a pointer coming from `malloc`.here is an example:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(char *s);

int main()
{
    char *str = "SABABA";
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

    func1(str);

    //ptr may have null value,that's why we check in func1
    func1(ptr);

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "ptr may have null value,that's why we check in func1" is not true. `func1` will only check `*ptr`, not including other 9 chars.